# C++ syntax for if, else if

Tags: c++

Hello I am new to C++ and I am having problems with my syntax for `if` statements.

My code below gives me several errors:

> expected primary expression before float, expected ')' before float, expected ')' before else.

I don't understand what the problem is since I tried following examples of other codes.

I am using codeblocks.

```
bool didYouPassTheCourse(float avgT, float avgQ, float avgA, float markF)
{
    float tutorial = avgT * 0.1;
    float ass = avgA * 0.3;
    float quiz = avgQ * 0.2;
    float exam = markF * 0.4;
    float finalGrade = (tutorial+ass+quiz+exam) / 1;

    if ((float avgQ < 50) || (float markF < 50))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (finalGrade >= 50)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You put `float avgQ`, and `float markF` in your first if statement. You can't declare variables in the boolean conditions section. It should be `avgQ < 50`, and `markF < 50`

Comment: When using a variable, don't prefix it with the variable's type.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float` portion from `float avgQ < 50` and `float markF < 50`

Not sure how you got the idea that was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if ((/*float*/ avgQ < 50) || (/*float*/ markF < 50))
```

Comment: Please don't place such enforcing comments. I understand you're eager about the rep gain, but there's nothing helpful about doing so, but just letting appear yourself being about after the 15 rep.